# Как хранить картинки для сайта?

Tags: html, mysql, база-данных, postgresql

Веб-странички хранятся в `BLOB`.

Стоит ли хранить картинки прямо в них как `base64`, или лучше как файлы в папке на сервере?

В чем преимущества и недостатки таких способов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше всего не совершать дополнительных действий с сущностями и хранить их как есть. Т.е. файлы оставлять файлами. Если вдруг вам однажды захочется заняться оптимизацией, например сделать уменьшение размеров загружаемых страниц, то в первую очередь большой выигрыш можно будет получить ужав картинки. Если картинки будут в файлах, то задача их ужатия будет проста - выполнение одного несложного скрипта. Если же они будут в Base64 храниться внутри HTML кода, то задача будет радикально сложнее. Ну и так вы ещё и размер БД сократите, что положительно скажется на размерах и скорости бэкапов БД.

Из минусов - картинки надо хранить в папках, заморачиваться с их подключением в HTML, но это не слишком сложно.

Comment: Меня беспокоит, ухудшит ли хранение HTML вмести с base64 в атрибутах src взаимодействие клиент-сервер?

Comment: Взаимодействие клиент-сервер это, на определённом уровне абстракции - просто обмен строчками между 2 компами. Что именно находится в строках этих - не имеет никакого значения. Проблема с Base64 в HTML может возникнуть только на этапе отрисовки HTML - но это будет уже проблема в браузере, его движке, что, по факту никак не пересекается с тем что и как вы храните в БД. По идее браузеры должны уметь отрисовывать картинки в HTML в Base64 формате.

Comment: Да, ухудшит. Дело в том, что картинки кэшируються, а  base64 в атрибутах src - вряд ли.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Т.е. в base64 безопасней, так они не попадут в кэш вошедшего пользователя? И наверно сложнее их украсть...

Comment: С этой точки зрения, на компе пользователя - кажеться да. Все таки base64 в атрибутах src "best practice" не являеться если для этого нет вязкая прчина. Обмен данных с сервером при перезагрузки - больше.

Comment: Если картинка отображается на конечном девайсе - то неважно в каком она формате в исходниках. У юзера всегда будет возможность ПКМ и "Сохранить как". Никакой защиты от кражи это не даст. Защиту может дать только судебное преследование по факту кражи. Техническими средствами картинки защитить невозможно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб мне главное не чтобы воровали, а чтобы все быстро работало.

Comment: Быстрее будет, если картинки будут в файлах, а не в Base64 при прочих равных обычно. Однако, мне кажется, вы впадаете во грех преждевременной оптимизации) Проблемы с быстродействием, в среднем, лучше решать по мере их возникновения. Не часто они закладываются на эта создания проекта.